# In Swift, is it possible to import a Swift Package only if iOS version is older than 15?

Tags: ios, swift

My app needs to support from iOS 12.

There's this swift package called `KeyboardLayoutGuide`:

https://github.com/freshOS/KeyboardLayoutGuide

In iOS 15, Apple introduced their own `keyboardLayoutGuide`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3752221-keyboardlayoutguide

This is causing a conflict due to the same name `keyboardLayoutGuide`. For example:

```
textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Note that by conflict, I don't mean any error. What's happening is that me using:

```
import KeyboardLayoutGuide
```

causes the app to only use the 3rd party library version even on newer devices running iOS 16 for example. I would like to run the "Apple" version of `keyboardLayoutGuide` on newer versions and the 3rd party library version on older than iOS 12 devices.

Is it possible to import the 3rd party `KeyboardLayoutGuide` ONLY if iOS is older than 15? Or is it possible to specify which `keyboardLayoutGuide` to use?

Comment: you could try this approach,
 `#if !canImport(UIKit.KeyboardLayoutGuide)
     import KeyboardLayoutGuide
 #endif`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I changed it to `#if !canImport(UIKit.UIKeyboardLayoutGuide)
import KeyboardLayoutGuide
#endif` however, it's still importing the 3rd party library version even on newer iOS 17. What am I missing?

Comment: Can't you check for os version instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson there's `if #available(iOS 13, *) {}` but I can't seem to be able to use for import. I think it can be used in functions only.

Comment: As someone who has just converted all the views in our app to use the Apple keyboard layout guide _after_ we _no longer_ had to support iOS 14 or earlier, I can really see how this would be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easiest to fork the `KeyboardLayoutGuide` package repo and rename things so they don't conflict with the UIKit implementation. Looks like there are already some [forks](https://github.com/freshOS/KeyboardLayoutGuide/forks) that have done this, such as [this one](https://github.com/AlexSeverinov/KeyboardLayoutGuide/commit/10759d65a77ddbd350a00db3a3434d490ec6be57).

Alternatively you could import the `KeyboardLayoutGuide` in another file and set up a custom extension method on `UIView` which redirects to the package's implementation. Then in your app code you could do an OS version check and switch between the two implementations.

For example:

```swift
// In another file

import KeyboardLayoutGuide
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    var oldKeyboardLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide {
        keyboardLayoutGuide
    }
}
```

In your code somewhere:

```swift
var guide : UILayoutGuide
if #unavailable(iOS 15.0) {
    guide = view.oldKeyboardLayoutGuide
} else {
    guide = view.keyboardLayoutGuide
}
textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

(or this could be another extension on `UIView` with some other name for `keyboardLayoutGuide`)

Note haven't actually tried this out, so it may need some tweaks or it may not actually work at all .

Comment: The second way worked well. Instead of "Inside the custom package", I just put that extension in another file which also imports the 3rd party `KeyboardLayoutGuide`. Then in my code, I used `#unavailable` to use this extension and otherwise use the Apple version. I edited your answer a tiny bit.